# Does the "no primitives in container" rule apply to arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, guava, bimap

I have recently been trying to implement a simple genetic algorithm. I need to use an inversible map which stores pairs of `(Character,4 bits)`. I chose Guava's `BiMap` for this task. However tests will not pass because of an `int` array which I chose for the bits storage.

Is `int[]` a primitive type? Would the use of a `Vector` or `List` of integers be a more appropriate tool for this task?

Comment: Which tests wouldn't pass?

Comment: assertEquals(new int[] {1,1,1,1},_CharacterDefinedInClass_)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is not that `int[]` is a primitive. An array in Java is an object. The problem is that it is an object **which does not override the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods**.

Since it doesn't override them, they are the same as those of Object, where objects are equal only if they are identical (i.e. references to the same instance).

Basically:

```
int[] a = new int[] {1,1,1,1};
int[] b = new int[] {1,1,1,1};
System.out.println( a.equals(b) );
```

You are probably expecting this to print `true`, but it will print `false`, because you created two distinct arrays, and it checks whether the arrays are the same object, not whether their content is the same!

In all probability, if you also add

```
System.out.println( a.hashCode() );
System.out.println( b.hashCode() );
```

You'll also get two different hash codes.

For this reason, arrays are not very suitable to use in collections that check for equality/uniqueness. They are good as the *value* in a standard `Map`, but not as the *key*. And in a Guava `BiMap` they can be used for neither key nor value.

What should you do?

You should use an object which overrides the `equals()` and `hashCode()` so that if the contents are the same, `equals()` returns `true` and the same value is returned from `hashCode()` on both.

If you want something relatively compact, you can represent the bits with a `Byte` object. You can use bit manipulation operators with it.

Or you can use a `BitSet` which is a Java standard container for bits.

Be careful, as `BitSet` is mutable. Mutable objects might not behave well when used in value-sensitive data structures like hash tables, because most implementations can't tell when you changed the value and so they can't move it around in the hash buckets accordingly. Don't set or clear any bits in the object once it is stored in the `BiMap`!

Comment: Thank you very much for exhaustive answer. I also would like to ask: would encoding bits as String be considered as bad programming practice?

Comment: Personally, I would prefer `BitSet`. `String` would be wasteful, allow values that are not bits, and the usage will be less obvious to anybody reading the code.

Comment: See also Guava's [Equivalence](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html), which effectively lets you provide custom `equals()`/`hashCode()` implementations for anything.

Comment: @paffciu I'd go for a `Byte` (or `Integer`) as it's more than big enough for your 4 bits. It's a bit low-level, but `BitSet` is mutable, which means you can run into funny hard to debug problems when you modify it by accident. Your own class wrapping a `BitSet` or a `boolean[]` would be probably best as long as speed doesn't matter (most of the time it doesn't).

Comment: @maaartinus its my own project, i care only about learning what genetic algorithms is all about, so performance will be my target later :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is `int[]` primitive type?

No. Java arrays are not primitive types, even when their individual elements are primitive.

> Will using vector or list of integers be appropriate tool for such task?

Neither `Vector<T>` nor `List<T>` could store primitives without "boxing" them into wrappers. However, if you need only four bits, you could use a single `byte`, which has eight bits available for storage.

To extract a bit `k` from a `byte`, use `(b & (1 << k)) != 0` expression. When this expression evaluates to `true`, bit `k` is set to `1`; otherwise, it is set to `0`.

To set a bit `k` in a byte to `1`, use `b |= (1 << k)`. To reset bit `k` to `0` use `b &= ~(1 << k)`

Comment: Thank you very much. I still have to store those bits in Map. In that case byte won't be appropriate, will it?

Comment: @paffciu Correct. You would need to use some other way of doing the map. I think Guava has some Java containers that store primitives, but I am not sure which ones.